# name of the file from /proc that is used to pass information from boot-loader to kernel

Tags: kernel, filesystem, bootloader

I am revising for LPI exam ,and i cannot  know this information which is :

#### the name of the file resides in `/proc` that is used to pass information from boot-loader to kernel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely they want `/proc/cmdline` as an answer

Comment: Thx guys . It was passed today و الحمد لله

Answer (score 1):

Florian Diesch is correct.  You can find information on this on the `man` page for `proc`.

> **/proc/cmdline**
>
> Arguments passed to the Linux kernel at boot time.  Often done  via  a  boot  manager  such  as  lilo(8) or grub(8).

From my 14.04 terminal, I can `cat` my `/proc/cmdline` to see the parameters that my kernel was booted with:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=UUID=cabb338a-445e-4ed7-8f37-a78ddf5174b6 ro find_preseed=/preseed.cfg auto noprompt priority=critical locale=en_US quiet
```

Comment: Thx guys . It was passed today و الحمد لله